# Manifest merger package name conflict with library project

Tags: android, gradle, merge, android-manifest

I have an application that has several product flavors, each with its own applicationId, and each flavor needs its own AndroidManifest.xml. These product flavors have a library dependency. The library's package name is conflicting with the flavor's package name during the manifest merge, but I can't seem to work out a combination of arrangements that make it work.

This is my manifest for the library:

```
<manifest package="com.mylibrary">

</manifest>
```

This is my manifest for the productFlavor:

```
<tools:manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="com.flavor1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <permission android:name="com.flavor1.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.flavor1.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <permission
        android:name="com.flavor1.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <application
        android:vmSafeMode="true"
        android:name="com.mylibrary.Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name="com.mymainapp.MainActivity"
            tools:node="remove"/>

        <activity
            android:name="com.flavor1.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</tools:manifest>
```

And this is my base app's gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.myapp'
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 409
        versionName "v4alpha9"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'src/main/AndroidManifest.xml'
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
        }

        flavor1 {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/productFlavors/flavor1/res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/productFlavors/flavor1/java']
            manifest.srcFile 'src/productFlavors/flavor1/AndroidManifest.xml'

        }

        flavor2 {
            res.srcDirs = ['src/productFlavors/flavor2/res']
            java.srcDirs = ['src/productFlavors/flavor2/java']
        }
    }
    productFlavors {

        flavor1 {
            applicationId 'com.flavor1'
        }

        flavor2 {
            applicationId 'com.flavor2'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile project(':mylibrary')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    compile 'com.mindscapehq.android:raygun4android:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
}
```

And my error is:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':myapp:processFlavor1DebugManifest'.
>   Manifest merger failed : Attribute tools:manifest@package value=(com.flavor1) from (unknown)
>       is also present at [android:mylibrary:unspecified] AndroidManifest.xml:3:5-44 value=(com.mylibrary).
>       Attributes of  elements are not merged.